# Converting md5 hash to bigint in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

in postgres, I am using  this function to convert a md5 hash to bigint:

`SELECT ('x'||substr(md5('text'),1,16))::bit(64)::bigint;`

The result would be `2067805253194386918` for this query.

How can I do this in NodeJS/Javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `crypto` package (included in NodeJs) and new `BigInt` type.

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
const md5 = crypto.createHash('md5').update('text').digest('hex');
const bigInt = BigInt(`0x${md5.substring(0, 16)}`);
```

Comment: Thanks @Anatoly! The first work when postgres gives a positive bigint. For example `text--123` as input would give `-7562545582615599264` in postgres but in nodejs `10884198491093952352`. How can I handle those cases?

Comment: This issue is because in PostgreSQL BigInt is 64 bit and higher order bit equals to 1 means negative value in contrast to JS BigInt which has more bits that's why this hex value is positive in JS. If it's suitable you can take 15 instead of 16 characters and add 0 at the beginning. That way all values in PostgreSQL will be positive and will be equal to those values in JS.

Comment: I have found the solution. The trick was asIntN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt/asIntN


`const signed64 = BigInt.asIntN(64, bigInt); // -7562545582615599264n`